# Scaling in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have some questions about scaling with ASP.NET environment. I'm in the start to build an application that I hope will get a lots of users, and if that's the case I need to know more about scaling.

It's heavly depends on user generated content, other users needs to be notified when content change by pooling AJAX calls, WebSockets it's not an option.

I know the basic stuff don't read from DB, put in memory, but how to do this in a webfarm?

How should the system handle if user content are created on Webserver 1, and the other users are request objects from Webserver 2. How does we notify the users without haveing to go thru DB? Making a lots of internal requests? Using some distributed cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're expecting to need this scalability from day 1, look into AppFabric: http://www.slideshare.net/chrduf/scale-your-data-tier-with-windows-server-app-fabric

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server/appfabric.aspx

If it's something you're expecting to see a lot further down the line it may be best to get on and write the app with what you know first with a view to refactoring to AppFabric later though.  That will allow you to get something out there, rather than bogged down in learning a new technology, so that when you come to refactor, you have a better understanding of your own product which will benefit you in making decisions on any new platforms.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using SQL Server, check out `SqlDependency` object combined with IIS `Cache`.  Basically, if the underlying recordset changes from Server1 and the content is updated in the database, all the other web servers will be notificed to update their local copies.  Under the covers, SqlDependency uses Service Broker, so you might want read up on that as well.

More info:

[Caching in ASP.NET with the SqlCacheDependency Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx)

Comment: Ok cool, is it effective or will it have a big performance impact?

Comment: From what I understand, SqlDependency registers a 'listener' on the SQL Server, so it's event based instead of 'poll based'. When a change occurs, a push event occurs so no communication occurs until the underlying recordset changes.

Answer (score 0):

The below are some of the products that serves distributed cache with pub/sub machinism

1) Oracle's Coherence http://coherence.oracle.com/display/COH34UG/Real+Time+Client+-+RTC it is  also have .net version (port from java)

2) Windows AppFabric Distributed Caching http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731(v=azure.10).aspx this is similar to Coherence syntactically

Another cheap option is using Nodes.js

Comment: How will Nodes.js help? Does it synchronize the cache between servers?

Comment: @SimonEdström Im afraid I cannot explain clearly on Nodes.js please read on this link what I mean http://faye.jcoglan.com/node.html